# How do I implement this piece of python code using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to find a recursive way to do this by passing the number of *for* loops in a recursive function:

```
def non_recursive():
  combinations = []

  for i in range(2): # first character
    for j in range(2): # second character
      for k in range(2): # third character
        combinations.append([i, j, k])

  return combinations

print(non_recursive())
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

In this example 3 *for* loops were used. The function prototype for the recursive way should look like this:

```
def recursive(number_of_iterations): # number of iterations = length of each list
  # implementation goes here!
```

As a beginner, I have no idea how to approach this. If anyone can help I really appreciate it!

Comment: in recursion you should have a stop condition, in this case it should be [number_of_iterations == 0], case that generates an empty array. Otherwise, calculate with number_of_iterations-1, and from any calculated combination, create 2 others, one starting with 1, and another starting with 0.

Comment: At least in this case, you just need `itertools.product`: `product(range(2), number_of_iterations)`.

Comment: @chepner Yeap! That's exactly what I want, but I would like to see code for a recursive way to get this. But this already helped me. Thanks.

Comment: Consider this: You can divide the `k`-element combinations into pairs: `[0,0,0]` and `[1,0,0]` would be one such pair, `[0,0,1]` and `[1,0,1]` another, etc. You can form each pair from a single element of the `k-1`-element combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine each result from recursive(n-1) with [0] and with [1]:

Here's an example using a two level list comprehension:

```
def recursive(n):
    if n == 1: return [[0],[1]]
    return [ r+[b] for r in recursive(n-1) for b in [0,1] ]


print(recursive(3))

# [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

These type of combinatoric functions however are usually defined as generators so that results can be processed without having to generate and store all the values in a big list:

```
def recursive(n):
    if n == 1:
        yield [0]
        yield [1]
    else:
        for r in recursive(n-1):
            yield r+[0]
            yield r+[1]

for combo in recursive(3): print(combo)
```

**[EDIT]** you can generalize this further by providing (variable) range sizes as parameters:

```
def multiRange(n,*rest):
    for i in range(n):
        for r in multiRange(*rest) if rest else [tuple()]:
            yield (i,)+r
```

output:

```
for x,y,z in multiRange(2,3,2):
    print((x,y,z))

(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
```

*this would be useful to get all the coordinates of a multi-dimentional matrix (or list of lists)*

It could be used with parameter unpacking for your specific example:

```
for combo in multiRange(*[2]*3): print(combo)

(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```